# Backing up local files of particular extensions to cloud providers

Tags: backup, online-backup

I want to back up my files to the cloud.

I would gladly backup entire folders however since as I have hundreds of GB it is too much space for most free solutions.

As a result I've set out to only include in the backup list files of a certain extension from those folders (e.g. *.docx, *.m etc), all of which take up little-enough space (<5 GB). Even that proves to be challenging.

I've tried some commercial solutions:

- iDrive offers 5GB for free, however their software doesn't allow selecting file types (only exclusions)
- Google Drive's software only enables backing up photos and videos, and not all files (let alone custom file extensions) within given folders
- Degoo (as several other [recommended](https://www.cloudwards.net/the-top-5-cloud-companies-with-large-free-service-plans/) providers) claims it is free but actually asks you to select a paid option at sign-up

Are there any ways around this or other solutions that I can try?

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I thought I did - I am trying to find a free online backup software that enables backing up only certain file types on the local PC....

Comment: Note that the question is broad enough to not be off-topic for the reasons you mention, i.e. I am open to suggestions of solutions not involving any particular provider but instead a different type altogether, such as LAN-based backup software etc (although I'd prefer to keep it online).

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ might be the place for this, if anywhere. It's off-topic for here, it's basically a shopping question - [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: I've made an attempt to remove the shopping request side of this question, but I'm not sure if it is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to considered using a software back up to make a local copy of those particular file extensions that you need, and only using a cloud back up on this copied folder / drive.

Comment: Can we resist the temptation to answer completely off-topic questions. It gives people the impression - & quite rightly if people do answer - that they can ask just anything they like & get a response.

Comment: Very good idea, thank you! (and sorry @Tetsujin for the off-topicness; and thanks for letting me know about the recs site)

Answer (score -2):

I used Mozy for a while. They were free up to a limit. I was able to select specific items. But memory is lacking so check it out.

Comment: Can we resist the temptation to answer completely off-topic questions. It gives people the impression - & quite rightly if people do answer - that they can ask just anything they like & get a response.